# Quitar formulación con VBA de un libro completo

Tags: vba

Lo se aplicar a un rango, a una celda, pero a un libro completo no.

¿Sabéis que metodo emplear?

He probado con lo siguiente pero me va relativamente lento:

```
Sub ctrlccrtlvEspecial()
    Dim wsh As Worksheet
    For Each wsh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        wsh.Cells.Copy
        wsh.Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Puedes tratar cada hoja como una matriz de celdas y mediante un bucle externo vas leyendo el libro

Answer (score 1):

Así debería irte rápido:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ctrlccrtlvEspecial()

    Dim arr
    Dim wsh As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each wsh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With wsh
            arr = .UsedRange.Value
            .UsedRange.Value = arr
        End With
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```